# Topology, connectivity and open sets

Tags: general-topology

I have an intuitive idea of topology, that it is about which things/points in a set are connected to each other.

I read the formal definition of topology and tried to understand, but I don't see no connectivity things in there. In fact metric at least gives me an idea of which points are close by having a distance function, but not the definition of topology.

Even in the set of real numbers, the set $(4,5)$ U $(6,7)$ are in the topology of real number, but they aren't connected or anything. So how does topology tell me which points are connected to which points, like perhaps a network topology does in computer networks. How can I form such an image of a space using open sets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to develop intuition in topology?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576593/how-to-develop-intuition-in-topology)

Comment: Is it ok to completely change a question after there are answers to the orginial one?

Comment: @Iota please don't change dramatically the content of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Connectivity is not necessarily the best way to think about topology. It's more about a classification of sets that are called "open", and these open sets can imply certain facts about the space such as connectivity, compactness, etc. But the open sets themselves in the topology can be either connected or disconnected, there are no restrictions for this.

The basis elements of the standard topology on the real line are open intervals $(a,b)$, so any union (disjoint unions as well) or finite intersection of those is an open set, hence in the topology. In a metric space the basis elements are open balls $B_r(x)$, i.e. $r$-radius balls around points $x$.

Comment: Is there a reason why we do all these abstract things? Perhaps some reason that we even started doing it

Comment: Abstraction is about creating a setting where we have the language to ask and answer questions that we're interested in.  Topology succeeds very well in this regard.  Look into the Seven Bridges of Konigsberg to see an application that I think will interest you.

Comment: @ChrisDugan ,T. Eskin Thanks for your inputs. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Iota: Regarding your edits, connectivity in networks has to do with the connected components of the network under the standard topology of a network. The same way like the standard topology on the real line classifieds different subsets of the real line as connected or disconnected. But connectivity is also not necessarily related to closeness of points either: points close to each other can be in disconnected parts.

Answer (score 1):

Topology can be equivalently described by the closure operator, which intuitively says, which points are infinitely close to which sets (a metric would tell you the exact distance between a point and a set). This could be thought of as when a point is “connected” to a set.

Answer (score 0):

Topology gives the minimum setting for the notions of continuity, limits, and, yes, connectedness.  However, that doesn't mean that every topology or topological space is connected; it only means that it provides enough structure to allow us to define connectedness.

A topological space, $X$, is a set which cannot be separated by two open sets.  That is, $X$ is connected iff there exist no open $A, B$ such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \cup B = X$.  A subset $E \subseteq X$ is connected iff it is connected in the subspace topology (the topology inherited from $X$ where a subset $U \subseteq E$ is open iff $U \cap X$ is open in the topology on $X$).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space.  These are the topological definitions that give us the machinery to detect connectedness.

To address your example directly, you are correct that $(4, 5) \cup (6, 7)$ is open in the topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but open sets need not be connected.  In this case, let $A := (4, 5)$ and $B := (6, 7)$ and we see that this set is not connected, as you intuitively knew.

A network topology in computer networks is more like a graph in mathematics, which can in turn be treated topologically.  I suggest that you look into Graph Theory, the seven bridges of Konigsberg, and Hamiltonian Paths if you haven't already.

Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it helps to try to understand what 'pathwise connected' means before understanding 'connected'.  A subset M of a topological space is pathwise connected, if there is a continuous path from x to y in M for each pair x,y in M.  If you consider the graphical representation of a network M on a sheet of paper X (considered as the real plane) as a topological space (with a euclidean metric topology), the notion of pathwise connectedness will be just what you want it to be: it will recover what you mean by 'a connected network': If there is a path in the network between any two points of the network the drawing is pathwise connected.

In this context you can define the continuity of the path in metrical terms. ($\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0$ ...). So far, nothing forces you to do more abstract topology. However, once you have a (metric) definition of open set you can observe the following: Assume $x,y\in M\subset X$. If it is possible to find two disjoint open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ in $X$, so that $M\subset U_1\cup U_2$, you cannot find a continuous path from $x_1$ to $x_2$.

[Just a sketch of how to prove this: In metric spaces you can easily prove, that for a ontinuous map in the metric sense the preimage of an open set has to be open. If there were a continuous path $c:[0,1]\to M$, $c(0)=x$, $c(1)=y$, we would obtain $c^{-1}(U_1)\cup c^{-1}(U_2)=[0,1]$, i.e. $[0,1]$ would be the union of two sets open in $[0,1]$.  You can now obtain a contradiction, for example by considering the supremum $s$ of all $t\in U_1$, which cannot be in $U_1$ (open), and cannot be in $U_2$, because otherwise a neighbourhood would be in $U_2$, so $s$ can't be the supremum of values in $U_1$.]

The summary of the above: If a metric space is the union of two disjoint non-empty open sets, it cannot be pathwise connected.

The property to be "union of two disjoint non-empty open sets" is chosen as the definition of "not connected" in the topological sense, its opposite is called "cannected", though it is considerably weaker than the intuitive notion of pathwise connectedness. We have sketched the proof of:

M not connected $\Rightarrow$ M not pathwise connected

which is equivalent to

M pathwise connected $\Rightarrow$ M connected

It is often handy to have a *weaker notion* of some interesting notion at hand.  Now you can look for examples of subsets of the plane which are connected,  but not pathwise connected.

Happily, all this remains true, if we drop the necessity of X to be a metric space, but assume it has a topology only, and define continuity in topological terms.  In order to convince you that topology is really nice and useful I would have to come up with at least one example of an interesting topological space that does not have a metric structure. Ay, there's the rub. The interesting examples I think of are not so easy after all (weak topologies of duals of non-separable linear spaces, Zariski topology on varieties.) Maybe someone else comes up with a striking example.